# how to decode utf-8 in php from utf-8 python encode?

Tags: python, php, utf-8

This the code in python

**value.py**

```
print('Print  Smile  2nd Best Private'.encode('utf-8'))
# b'Print \xf0\x9f\x98\x80 Smile \xf0\x9f\xa5\x87 2nd Best Private'
```

**value.php**

```
#get value from value.py
$bio=rtrim(ltrim($temp[2]));
$bio = preg_replace("/U\+([0-9a-f]{4,5})/mi", '&#x${1}', $bio);
echo ($bio);

echo($bio);
//output = \xf0\x9f\x98\x80 Smile \xf0\x9f\xa5\x87 2nd Best Private'
```

Comment: Your regex is searching for "U+", which doesn't appear anywhere in your input. I'm guessing you've copied this from somewhere without attempting to understand it.

Comment: The construct `print('some string'.encode('utf8'))` is useful for inspecting string values, but it's not a convenient exchange format (because it's a Python-specific representation and not easily converted back, especially not in a different programming language). Instead, write the encoded bytes to a binary (non-text) filehandle or use JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my *naive* approach (implemented in Windows).

**Scripts**:

```
type .\SO\71805811.py
```

> ```
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
>
> print('Print  Smile  2nd Best Private'.encode('utf-8'))
> ```

```
type .\SO\71805811.php
```

> ```
> <?php
> var_dump($argn);
> $pattern = '(\\\\x(?=[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))';
> //                ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑  positive lookahead assertion
> $replacement = '=';
> $encoded = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $argn);
> var_dump(quoted_printable_decode($encoded));
> ?>
> ```

**Output**:

```
.\SO\71805811.py
```

> ```
> b'Print \xf0\x9f\x98\x80 Smile \xf0\x9f\xa5\x87 2nd Best Private'
> ```

```
.\SO\71805811.py | \php8\php.exe -F .\SO\71805811.php
```

> ```
> string(65) "b'Print \xf0\x9f\x98\x80 Smile \xf0\x9f\xa5\x87 2nd Best Private'"
> string(41) "b'Print  Smile  2nd Best Private'"
> ```

Comment: Shouldn't the character class in the look-ahead be `[0-9A-Fa-f]`? These are hex digits after all.

Comment: @lenz you are right; code fixed.